# Datagrid combobox does not bind to a property - wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a datagridComboBoxColumn. The items source of the datagrid is a custom class called Products which has a property called Installer (also a custom class called Contact).

I want to bind the datagridComboBoxColumn itemsSource to all the Contacts, and the selected value of the comboBox to the Installer. This is not working, could anyone please give me a hand? Thanks in advance

It would be much appreciated. I have seen other similar posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565236/binding-comboboxcolumn-to-collection-from-datagrids-itemssource-in-wpf-datagrid) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724180/problem-binding-datagridcomboboxcolumn-itemssource) ) but it's not exactly the same situation.

My xaml code:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="productsList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*" GridLinesVisibility="None">
                <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Ref}" 
                                    />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Product}" 
                                    />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Installer"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Installer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"/>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

My code-behind:

```
 public partial class CatalogPage : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<CatalogProduct> mProductList = new ObservableCollection<CatalogProduct>();

    public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            return Parent.mContactsPage.GetContacts();
        }
    }

    private LocalConfigurationPage Parent { get; set; }
    public CatalogPage(LocalConfigurationPage localConfigurationPage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Parent = localConfigurationPage;

        productsList.ItemsSource = mProductList;


    }
}
```

This is the CatalogProduct class:

```
 public class CatalogProduct
{
    public string Ref { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Contact Installer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: apply updatesourcetrigger too.

Comment: Sorry @AnjumSKhan, could you specify a bit more detailed? Where shall I apply this? As a property to the DataGrid?

Comment: ... to comboboxcolumn in your selecteditem binding

Comment: Thanks @AnjumSKhan. I did it ( see my post updated) but nothing changed. In the data grid it doesn´t even appear the combobox.

Comment: where is Installer in your code ?

Comment: I have added the class CatalogProduct to my post so you can see that it has a property called Installer which is a custom class (Contact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you have done wrong here.

1. `Contacts` is present in `CatalogPage` so, `{Binding Contacts}` wont work. This is because `DataContext` of a `DataGridRow` is the `Item` shown for that row. For your row, it would be `CatalogProduct`, and there is no `Contacts` there.

   Instead you have to do this :

   `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Contacts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`
2. Secondly, there are known issues with `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, so always use this :

   ```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Installer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Contacts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```
3. And finally, if you want to update your `ComboBoxColumn` with `Installer` value, implement change notification for `Installer`, and set `Mode=TwoWay` for `SelectedItem`. Otherwise, right now it will work `Combobox -> Installer` and not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! I have done the changes you said and still doesn´t work. There is an improvement tho, now I can see the combobox, but it is empty. I think I am missing something obvious...
I have set a breakpoint in the get statement of the Contacts property, but it doesn´t break there. I was expecting to break when the combobox ask for the Contacts.
 Usually I do this with code-behind instead of bindings, but here, if I name the ComboBox, I cannot access to it from code-behind, that´s why I am a bit lost here, sorry. Thanks for your help @AnjumSKhan

Comment: @chincheta73 Your Contacts property is private, make it public.

Comment: I already tried that before but didn´t update my post sorry. Now my post is updated, the Contacts property is public, and nothing changed.

Comment: do you mean changing the DataGridTemplateColumn to a  DataGridComboBoxColumn again and set the ItemsSource to the value you proposed? I already tried that and still doesn´t work. in the grid it doesn´t even appear a comboBox.